# Creating new database with owner and password in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to set up a database in PostgreSQL (I'm using psql 10.5)

typed in

```
CREATE DATABASE name OWNER teamname WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

but upon entering I got this error.

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE name OWNER teamname WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE name OWNER teamname WITH PASSWORD 'passwor...
                                              ^
postgres=#
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
CREATE DATABASE name WITH OWNER = 'owner_name';
```

Password of the user/owner is not specified here; the `owner_name` should already exist and have a password.

Comment: In case you wonder, to create a user:

CREATE USER user_name  WITH  PASSWORD 'password';

Answer (score 1):

`WITH PASSWORD` is an option under `CREATE USER` : [See Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createuser.html)

You may follow this order (running as postgres) of steps for your requirement to keep things clean.

```
CREATE USER teamname WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE DATABASE yourdb OWNER teamname;
```